# Varechina e candeggina

Tags: word-choice, single-words

Volevo sapere se la candeggina è semplicemente una marca di varechina.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da Treccani:

> **[varechina](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/varechina/)**: Nome di liquidi usati per candeggiare fibre tessili, tessuti, ecc., costituiti da soluzioni diluite di ipoclorito di sodio
>   (con tenore di cloro attivo del 2-4%, o più concentrato), contenenti
>   anche carbonato e talora solfato di sodio.

mentre

> **[candeggina](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/candeggina/)**: Nome commerciale di un prodotto per bucato del tipo della varechina.

Come vedi la differenza è sottile e spesso vengono utilizzati come sinonimi l'uno dell'altro.